# Orocommerce : Products that should not be visible are

Tags: orocommerce

We are using Orocommerce version 3.

We have setup a number of differnent product categories and assigned products to these. We have also defined the permissions so that certain groups and cusotmers should not be able to see some of the products via the front end of the site.

When testing the site using two different cusotmers one which should and one which should not see the product when using the search and the product SKU both are able to view and potentially buy the product.

This only appears to be happening for certain products, which is odd.

We have reviewed the documentation here: [Oro Docs](https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/products/products/managing-product-visibility/) and feel we have followed it correctly.

Has any one come acrooss this before, what options do we have solve this?

Comment: Hi Matthew, Please share, what exact version of OroCommerce you are using, in "x.y.z" format. You can find it by running `composer info oro/commerce | grep version` command.

Comment: Hi @Anyt this is the version we are runnign at present: 3.0.0-rc (2018-05-31)

Comment: 3.0.0-RC version is not supported and never has been recommended for using in production. So there could be some bugs that are already fixed in a new version. Now we recommend upgrading to the latest available LTS version, it's 4.1.0.